# Calculate coordinates on the circle to draw N number of equal height rectangles

Tags: geometry

I am trying to divide a circle into several rows with each row containing multiple cells of equal height and width. In order to do this I would like to figure out how to divide the circle into N number of rows first and then divide that row into Mn number of cells for each row n.

For clarity below is the information available to draw the circle and rectangular cells inside the circle.

1. center cx, cy and radius r.
2. Number of rows is N.
3. All cells in all rows should have equal width and height.

I am specifically looking for a way to calculate all the x,y locations of both the ends of the rectangles that represent each row. These x,y coordinates must be on the circumference of the circle as in the sample picture below. But some edges of the row with in the circle may not be part of a full cell to meet the criteria of equal sides for each cell.

[Sample picture here](https://kvoqx44227.i.lithium.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/3950i45B04C9B115E132B/image-size/large?v=1.0&px=999)

And my attempt to draw this with Javascript is here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/spalakala/1dcph3gu/48/) But you can see the ends of my rectangles or not on the circle and I don't have a way to calculate the x,y coordinates.

Comment: I don't understand your question. I'm not sure what exactly you want to do and what problem you're facing.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri, see the attached picture. How do you determine the needed coordinates to draw that grid inside circle?

Comment: What properties does that grid have? It just seems like a square tiling.